# is it possible for gulp to have output path outside project

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

for example i have my laravel project which has this kind of structure

./
--assets
----postcss
------style.css

i want to output that style.css outside app folder(one level above root). Is that possible(i'm running elixir)

EDIT: - my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');


require('laravel-elixir-postcss');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir.extend('changePath', function() {
    gulp.task('css', function () {
        return gulp.src("./resources/assets/postcss/")
            .pipe($.cleanCss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("../css/style.css"));
});

elixir(function(mix) {

  mix.postcss('style.css', {
    plugins:[ 
      //require('csstyle'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
      //require('cssnext'),
      require('lost'),
      require('postcss-font-magician')
      // require('stylelint')
    ] 
  })
  .changePath();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go up a directory in your destination path? Ex:

```
 gulp.task('css', function () {
        return gulp.src("./assets/postcss/")
            .pipe($.cleanCss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("../some-folder/"));
 });
```

Comment: i'm still learning gulp/elixir. Do I need to extend elixir to add that gulp task?

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile? I'm not familiar with elixir or laravel, but for gulp you can output files to any directory on your machine.

Comment: I added my gulp.js file to first post

Comment: So if you change the path in gulp.dest() to something else does it work?

Comment: no. I'm getting error });

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: I was missing the closing `});` on my above post.

Comment: I corrected the error but it still points to default path it won't override it

Comment: I'm confused. What is the default path? Are you saying that no matter what path you supply in `gulp.dest()` it always outputs your css file to the same location?